# How to find the prev value of a cloumn grouped by two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

From the following table i want to find the new and previous code grouped by fname and lname.

```
fname | lname | code |
----------------------
jack  | jonas | 987  |  
nick  | fun   | 563  |  
jack  | jonas | 674  |
jack  | jonas | 672  |
```

Output Table:

```
fname | lname | new_code | prev_code |
-------------------------------------
jack  | jonas | 987      | 674
```

PS: '**distinct on**' is not supported in my case. I guess left join or pivot can be used.

Comment: it is postgresql

Comment: Is the "previous" code always the one with the smaller number?

Comment: there can be multiple rows (2 or more) with same fname and lname, but different code. They are sorted with latest date. I only need to get top two rows of same fname and lname and get the second row as previous. Code can be smaller or large from previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can get the most recent pair for each name using `distinct on` and `lag()`:

```
select distinct on (lname, fname) t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(code) over (partition by lname, fname order by datecol) as prev_code
      from t
     ) t
where prev_code is not null
order by lname, fname, date desc;
```

You can also do this without a subquery:

```
select distinct lname, fname,
       first_value(code) over (partition by lname, fname order by datecol desc),
       nth_value(code, 2) over (partition by lname, fname order by datecol desc)
from t;
```

However, you would still need a subquery to filter the values when the second code is there.

Or, you can use arrays:

```
select lname, fname,
       (array_agg(code order by datecol desc))[1] as code,
       (array_agg(code order by datecol desc))[2] as prev_code
from t
group by lname, fname
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: @xanjay . . . Not in Postgres.  Postgres doesn't support `pivot` (happily).

Comment: I mean using CASE.

Answer (score 1):

try like below by using `row_number()` widown function

```
with cte as
(
select *,
row_number() over(partition by fname,lname order by date desc) rn
from table_name
), cte1 as
(
select * from cte where rn<=2
), select fname,lname,
max(case when rn=1 then code end) as code,
max(case when rn=2 then code end) as prevcode fron cte1
group by fname,lnamae
```

Answer (score 1):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d270c8e67acf6253648960747eb97187)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (fname, lname)
        *,
        lead(code) OVER (PARTITION BY fname, lname ORDER BY my_date DESC) as prev
    FROM
        my_table
    ORDER BY 
        fname, lname, my_date DESC
) s
WHERE prev IS NOT NULL
```

1. `lead()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) gives you the previous code
2. `DISTINCT ON` filters the first data set of each group
3. If there is no previous code you can filter it with a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

you can use window functions first_value , nth_value e.g

```
select
distinct on (fname, lname)
first_value(fname ) over (PARTITION by fname, lname order by some_date desc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
first_value(lname ) over (PARTITION by fname, lname order by some_date desc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
nth_value(code,1) over (PARTITION by fname, lname order by some_date desc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
nth_value(code,2) over (PARTITION by fname, lname order by some_date desc RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
from public.tbl_test
```